# How do round decimals when writing dataframe in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


data = {'Days': ["Sunday", "Wednesday", "Friday"],
        'Predictions': [433.11, 97.9, 153.65]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
st.write(df)
```

streamlit writes dataframe with four decimals by default, but i expected two decimals. With `print()` it produces the expected, and when `st.write()` is used it produces the below output:

```
    Days     | Predictions
-------------|-------------
0   Sunday   |  433.1100  |
1   Wednesday|  97.9000   |
2   Friday   |  153.6500  |
```

I tried:

```
df.round(2)
```

but it didn't help.

Desired output format:

```
    Days     | Predictions
-------------|-------------
0   Sunday   |  433.11    |
1   Wednesday|  97.90     |
2   Friday   |  153.65    |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [**`df.style.format()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) method, you can specify the desired number of decimal places to override the default behavior of `pandas` in streamlit.
**Note:** This approach only provides the desired output format but when working farther you will have to still use the ***original dataframe*** which is `df`.

```py
formatted_df = df.style.format({"Predictions": "{:.2f}".format})
st.write(formatted_df)
```

You could also choose to write the dataframe without having to initialize a variable, like so:

```py
st.write(df.style.format({"Predictions": "{:.2f}"}))
```