# How to efficiently round data in a streamlit dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

Pandas' `.style.set_precision(2)` is completely stalling my streamlit app. Is there a more efficient way to round data that is displayed in a streamlit app using `st.dataframe`, `st.write`, or `st.table`?

I am simply trying to round my dataframe to two decimals. My data is ~60k rows and 43 columns. It displays instantly without using any rounding techniques, but when I add `.style.set_precision(2)`, my app completely stalls. I have to add `.head(1000)` and even then it still takes a lot longer to display than if I were to not set a precision at all. I’m shocked there isn’t a native rounding option yet. Is there a way to efficiently round my data? I would like to display it in full.

This works instantly, but displays multiple unnecessary trailing 0s for each `float` column:

```
st.dataframe(data)
```

This crashes my app:

```
st.dataframe(data.style.set_precision(2))
```

This works but takes way longer than I feel it should (and doesn't even display all of my data:

```
st.dataframe(data.head(1000).style.set_precision(2))
```

I am running streamlit 1.17.0. Also, streamlit apps have 1 GB of resources, and my dataframe comes nowhere near that, so I'm curious why this bottlenecking is occuring.

I've noticed setting the precision stalls in a jupyter notebook environment too, so is this a pandas thing?

## MRE:

Mock data:

```
    a    b        c      d       e
0 28.00 26.02   11.60   1.62    2.60
1 2.00  11.15   0.80    0.09    0.31
2 30.50 29.77   15.40   2.46    7.21
```

```
    data = data[cols]
    roundf = data.copy()
    numeric_cols = data.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
    roundf[numeric_cols] = roundf[numeric_cols].round(decimals=2)

    st.dataframe(roundf)
```

Displays as:

```
0 28.0000   26.0200 11.6000 15  1.6200  4   2.6000
1 2.0000    11.1500 0.8000  5   0.0900  0   0.3100
2 30.5000   29.7700 15.4000 15  2.4600  4   7.2100
```

streamlit 1.17.0, numpy 1.24.2, pandas 1.5.3

Looks like the same issue is occurring [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/cant-adjust-dataframes-decimal-places/1949)

Comment: Did you try - > [How do round decimals when writing dataframe in streamlit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310395/19290081)

Answer (score 1):

Can you test with [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) ?

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col"+str(i): np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C"])
                  if i%2==0 else np.random.randn(60000) for i in range(43)}
)

roundf = df.copy()
numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
roundf[numeric_cols] = roundf[numeric_cols].round(decimals=2)

st.dataframe(roundf)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: **NB** : If `df.dtypes.eq(np.number).all()` is *True*, use `st.dataframe(df.round(decimals=2))`.

Comment: For some reason this still results in the two extra trailing 0s for me. streamlit 1.17.0, numpy 1.24.2, pandas 1.5.3

Comment: Can you `print(df.dtypes)` and share a reproducible example ?

Comment: They are float64s. unfortunately, I cannot share this data. Sorry

Comment: I didn't asked for your real dataset. I'm sure you know about the MRE : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited. Apologies

Comment: Sorry, I still can't reproduce the issue with `round` on your example. I added the example I used as well (*by the way, I'm using the latests versions of all the packages*). I'll came back if I ever found a solution. Good luck ;)

Comment: Your example still gives me trailing 0s. Can you share your streamlit, numpy, and pandas versions?

Comment: Sure,  `streamlit==1.21.0`, `pandas==2.0.0`, `numpy==1.24.2`.

Comment: I updated to streamlit 1.21.0 and this fixed it the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `round` on the *same* line as the `st` printer, like so:

```
st.dataframe(
    df.round(decimals=2),
    column_config={"Name": st.column_config.Column(width="medium")},
)
```